# Finding an element of order $67$ modulo $2011$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primitive-roots

Suppose that we are given $p= 2011$, where $3$ is a primitive root (this is a given). Here is the question:

> Find an element of order $67$.

I know that $e_{p}(a) =$ (the smallest exponent $e \geq 1$ such that $a^e \equiv 1$ (mod $p$). But, this turns into the [Discrete Log Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), which makes it difficult to solve for $e$ since there is no general way of approaching these types of problems. How else can I approach this problem?

Comment: Hint:  67 divides 2010.

Comment: So there are a total of 66 elements that are of order $67$ modulo $2011$ correct? Now, I need to pick one out.

Comment: The title asks for one thing, the body another.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to change the title since I previously had another question in mind.

Comment: What is the order of $3^{30} \pmod{2011}$?

Comment: @Kyogre: How about $$(64, 74, 103, 133, 182, 278, 321, 326, 342, 434, 445, 460, 462, 468, 480, 550, 551, 554, 555, 559, 647, 714, 754, 776, 850, 857, 866, 887, 947, 948, 1013, 1039, 1077, 1116, 1127, 1146, 1176, 1187, 1188, 1244, 1269, 1286, 1333, 1365, 1400, 1402, 1414, 1419, 1439, 1454, 1499, 1561, 1589, 1593, 1601, 1625, 1633, 1704, 1743, 1778, 1798, 1836, 1864, 1914, 1951, 2003)$$ That, is there are $66$ of them.

Comment: Hint: can you find an element of $\mathbb{Z} / 2010 \mathbb{Z}$ of order 67?  If so, then knowing that 3 is a primitive root will tell you how to get an isomorphism between the abelian groups $\mathbb{Z} / 2010 \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{2011}^*$.

Comment: @MathLover I have no clue. I haven't had much practice with orders.

Comment: @Moo So any of those numbers is an element of order $67$ mod 2011? If so, how were you able to generate those numbers? I would really like to know.

Comment: Think about it.  If $3^{2010}\equiv 1 \mod 2010$ then $(3^{30})^{???} \equiv 1 \mod 2010$.  ... or put it this way.  What is $(3^{30})^k\equiv 1 \equiv 3^{2010}$, then what is $k$.

Comment: Well, in that case, $k = 67.$

Comment: So what is $(3^{30})^{67}?$.

Comment: This is congruent to $1$ modulo 2010.

Answer (score 2):

$2011$ is prime and $|3|$ is given to be $2010$.  So that $3^{2010} \equiv 1 \mod 2011$ and for any $k < 2011$ $3^k \not \equiv 1 \mod 2011$.

We don't have to prove that.  We were told that.

Notice that $(3^k)^m = 3^{km}$ so if $mk = 2010$ then $(3^k)^m \equiv 3^{km} = 3^{2010} \equiv 1 \mod 2011$.

So Let $m = 3^{\frac {2010}{67}}$.  Then $m^{67} = 3^{2010} \equiv 1 \mod 2011$ and if $k < 67$ then $m^k = 3^{\frac {2010}{67}*k}$ and $\frac {2010}{67}*k < 2010$ and so $m^k = 3^{\frac {2010}{67}*k}\not \equiv 1 \mod 2011$.

So $m = 3^{\frac {2010}{67}}$ has order $67$.

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are, in effect, told that $a=3^{30}\not\equiv1$ mod $2011$, so you know that $a^{67}=3^{30\cdot67}=3^{2010}\equiv1$ mod $2011$, by Fermat's little theorem for the prime $2011$.  This means the order of $a$ is a divisor of $67$. But since $67$ is prime, that divisor can only be $67$ itself.

If you want to find the residue $a=3^{30}$ mod $2011$ explicitly, you've got some squaring to do first:

$$\begin{align}
3^2&=9\\
3^4&=9^2=81\\
3^8&=81^2=6561\equiv528\\
3^{16}&=528^2=278784\equiv1266
\end{align}$$

so that

$$\begin{align}
3^{30}&=3^{16+8+4+2}\\
&\equiv1266\cdot528\cdot81\cdot9\\
&=(1266\cdot9)\cdot(528\cdot81)\\
&=11394\cdot42768\\
&\equiv1339\cdot537\\
&=719043\\
&\equiv1116
\end{align}$$